# How should a Beanstalk app talk to another Beanstalk app

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a GraphQL server Gateway app in NodeJS, which talks to a REST API server. I would like to deploy both using AWS Beanstalk, keeping the REST API server private (not exposed to the internet).

Gateway is talking to the REST API via HTTP.

How do I solve this communication between both and support future scaling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ElasticBeanstalk (EB) can operate in a [custom VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html). What's more it can operate in a [private subnet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/vpc.html#services-vpc-private).

Subsequently, you could create a VPC with public and private subnets, across 2 or 3 availability zones. You would place Gateway app in an EB environment in the **public subnets**, while the REST API EB environment in the **private subnets**. This way, the REST API wouldn't be accessible from the internet. Only the Gateway EB could communicate with it since they would be in the same VPC.

Regarding scaling. Each EB environment places your instances in an AutoScaling Group. For high-availability and scalability you would need to choose [load-balanced](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features-managing-env-types.html) EB environment type, rather then single-instance type.

The overall solution would be similar to the **three-tear architecture** , as shown for example [here](https://medium.com/the-andela-way/designing-a-three-tier-architecture-in-aws-e5c24671f124). The third-tear is database tier, so obviously you wouldn't have that. Also, instead of manually setting up the load balancers, autoscaling groups like in the example link, you would employ EB for that.

Comment: Sounds good Marcin, thanks.
Given it is an elastic scalable env, how can I know the IPs of my REST server instances, to use them from the Gateway?

Comment: @Aleks Hi. There will be internal load balancer in-front of your REST servers. Thus, in gateway you will connect to that, not to the instances directly.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a setup?

Comment: @Aleks Sadly not. The closes I could find was what I linked. In that link, everything is setup manually. WIth EB, the outcome would be same, but of course, the steps to achieve that would be different. You can always start development of such architecture, and if get stack or have some new questions, you can ask on SO :-)